# Disable all GUI popups and tooltips

Tags: gui-emacs, tooltip, popup

Can I disable this kind of a popup?[image]

I couldn't find anything besides `(setq x-gtk-use-system-tooltips nil)`, but it didin't help me unfortunately.

Comment: Note that GUI dialogs only ever appear in response to mouse events.  If you don't do things with the mouse, you won't see them at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not true. I definitely don't do things with a mouse when this dialog appears.

Comment: That's unusual behaviour, then.  Does your example happen when you use `C-x C-f` to visit such a symlink?  The prompt would normally be in the minibuffer in that scenario.  Does the same thing happen when you run `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: It happens when I press `Enter` to the link in the help window. Like "this function is defined in `file.el`", where `file.el` leads to the symlinked git repo.

Comment: emacs -Q works the same way for me

Comment: Very curious.  I wanted to try to replicate that, but I'm not entirely sure what you're describing.  Is `file.el` itself a symlink in that scenario?  I can replicate the prompt/query by creating a symlink to a version-controlled elisp library, byte-compiling the symlink, loading the compiled library, getting help on one of its functions, and following the link with RET; but in my case the prompt is in the minibuffer, as I expected it to be.

Comment: It seems that you're replicating correctly. I'm using straight.el which does exactly this with a 3rd party packages :) Magic though

Comment: Ah, `C-h v use-dialog-box` says "On some platforms, file selection dialogs are also enabled if this is non-nil." so I guess that's what's happening? Sorry for my confusion -- I was entirely oblivious to this working differently on different platforms. Which OS is this?

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux with i3wm, which uses X11

Comment: I've mostly used Debian and derivative GNU/Linux systems, and have never encountered this, to my recollection.  I'm not really familiar with Arch, but it seems surprising to me that it would be different.  I have no knowledge of how/why this platform-specific behaviour exists, though.  Thanks for the follow-ups -- I've learned something new here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable dialog windows set `use-dialog-box` to `nil`

```
(setq use-dialog-box nil)
```